# Deployment of Laravel app with Vue component on shared hosting - vue components are not displaying

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm testing process of deploying app with vue components on shared server. I have access to ssh. Npm is also installed. I check it with "node -v" command. The problem is that vue compoennts are not displaying. I tried to write "npm run production" but I receive an error 126. What should I do to display vue components? I know the voices that shared hosting is not the best choice but I'm just testing. I know that it's possible to turn on vue components on this hosting. I did it long time ago but I forgot how. My process of deployment had 3 steps:
1. Copy files (wihout public_html) from local disc to shared server w
2. Copy public_html do public_html on shared server
3. Changing paths in index.php inside public_html

App is almost working. The problem is with vue components. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need NodeJs in production. You just need to build it (CSS & JS) on your machine, then upload it. Run `npm run production` in your local machine, then the `public/css/app.css` and `public/js/app.js` will be available (depends on your configuration). Then, just upload these files, done.

Comment: @appson Can you more detail about your issue after running my advice? I mean what is the error exactly. Something like output from the browser console, etc. I can't help you more, without it.

Comment: @appson Fyi, you're using Laravel Mix, right? I just guessed you're using Laravel Mix, because by default Laravel artisans should use Laravel Mix.

Comment: I must correct my answer. When I'm running "npm run production" default component (I mean "example-component" ) is shown. But second component "vue -datepcicker" package installed by me is not dispalyed. On local machine two components are dispalyed correctly. I'm thinking now what is wrong with "vue-datepicker" Yes, I'm using Laravel mix by default.

Comment: So, now you've an issue with vue-datepicker? Maybe I can help you, but sorry this is stackoverflow, you should create another question (with more detail, screenshot, console output, etc) if your original issue is solved. Thanks

Comment: Thank you for help. I'm not sure if my orginal issue is solved. I was convinced if I run "npm run production" all components will be shown like in local machine. Do you think issue with datepicker component is separate issue caused by vue-datepicker package?

Comment: The problem with "vue-datepicker" was the cache problem. Thanks again for help.